# How can I get the value in the prompt put it in the value of this checkbox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, prompt

How can I get the value in the prompt put it in the value of this checkbox?

```java
<script type=text/javascript>   
function validate(d){
        if(document.getElementById('chk'+d).checked){
        var value = prompt("Enter Correct Quantity:", "");
            if(isNaN(value)){ 
                alert("Must be a Integer!");
            }else{
                if(value == ""){
                    value = null;
                }
                if(value!=null){
                    document.getElementById("value"+d).innerHTML=value; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to put the 'value' in the function validation to the value of the checkbox.

```
<br><input id='chk"+d+"' type='checkbox' name='error_"+d+"[]' onclick='validate("+d+")' value=''>Wrong Quantity&nbsp;<em id='value"+d+"'></em>
```

Your suggestions will be most appreciated.

Comment: id='chk"+d+"' what do you want to express.

Comment: the "d" there is the row number. the checkbox is actually placed in the table.

Comment: property value in 'id' 'name' is definitely a value only, you can't treat it as javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/yVN78/

Lots of html coding mistakes.

```
<input id='chk1' type='checkbox' name='error_1' onclick='validate("1")' value=''>Wrong Quantity&nbsp;<em id='value1'></em>
```

Comment: how can i get the value of the check box? if i call it in another page?

Comment: What value of the check box? I can't see any property in your <input> called 'value'.

Comment: You mean 'Wrong Quantity&nbsp;'?

Comment: or text inside <em id='value1'></em>?

Comment: the text inside <em id='value1'></em> should be the value of the che value of the check box.

Comment: That means you want the <input> element change its value property at the same time?

Comment: Very simple, just add a line: document.getElementById('chk' + d).value = value;